# Override CompilerHost

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a very special use case, where I need some custom compiler behaviour of Angular.

So basically, when I have an import in a TS file, like

```
import {TableComponent} from '../components/table-component.ts';
```

I want to change the path, so that in the end another file will get used

```
import {TableComponent} from '../../otherSource/components/table-component.ts';
```

I know what I need to do, but I don't know how I can override the Compiler Host of Angular/TS. I need some way, to override the method, where to compiler loads files.

Comment: Have you tried with path mapping? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Comment: Yes, but it seems that relative paths are not supported.